# Implement a custom JWT workflow

Tags: ios, node.js, security, authentication, jwt

I use nodejs for rest api's and client app is in both ios and android.

Normally the server generates or signs the JWT and send to the device. The device saves it in local and use it for subsequent requests.

But I am planning to implement a custom JWT scenario in my application.

The plan is to create a token for each request in the device itself and verify it in server.

So when the hackers steals the key, he cannot use it even for once, as the JWT is in invalid.

Also the token issuing client cannot request with the same token again.

Will this work or should i follow general standards of JWT implementation. Any experts ideas ?

If yes, i have few questions

1) Whether it is feasible to retrieve the key(or logic behind this) from the client device and compromise the security

2) Will there be a performance degrade in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice retrieve the keys from client device which will become security threat in the future.

If you want to create custom JWT in your case,you can have a rest service developed and named as auth service which will be used for authentication. You can call the auth service with necessary data and in the back-end you can validate the details passed.

Thereafter, you can create your own JWT with the expire time accordingly and pass as a response which can be used for other rest calls until it get expired.